# SSIS Derived Column Transformation Expression Divisor 0 Error

Tags: ssis

I was looking through this post from last year by Jax: Division by zero occurred in the expression in derived column ssis, which seemed to cover my questions, but Jax was able to answer it himself and didn't provide an answer. I'd like to know what method was used to alleviate the Divisor =0 error.

My question is this expression: ISNULL(TotalPayrollCost) ? 0 : (ExcessCapacity * RouteVehicleCostAlloc) / TotalPayrollCost and I confirmed that TotalPayrollCost is showing 0 in the data viewers.

I thought there would be a solution using ISNULL and NULLIF together, but I just can't quite get that to work and NULLIF doesn't work in the Transformation Editor. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should the result be when TotalPayrollCost is 0?

Answer (score 3):

The ISNULL logic is only going to handle when `TotalPayrollCost` is NULL (shocking, I know). I'm assuming since you mention isnull/nullif you'd want to take the same logic for that value being 0 as null so your expression would become

```
(ISNULL(TotalPayrollCost) || TotalPayrollCost == 0) ? 0 : (ExcessCapacity * RouteVehicleCostAlloc) / TotalPayrollCost
```

That basically reads If the total payroll cost is null or if the total payroll cost is 0, then return zero. Otherwise, do this calculation

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry I didn't get back to you right away! And so yes, the ISNULL function did seem misleading as to what I needed to accomplish. I was trying to use it with NULLIF and forgot to take it back out. However, let me see if this works - looks like it should!

Comment: Perfect! I only needed to add the additional "=" making it (ISNULL(TotalPayrollCost) || TotalPayrollCost == 0) ? 0 : (ExcessCapacity * RouteVehicleCostAlloc) / TotalPayrollCost. I'm obviously still learning the syntax in SSIS, which is different than just writing SQL or using MS Access, etc. Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh no, I've used the pattern `ISNULL(NULLIF(ColA, 'SomeValue'), 'SafeValue'))` in lieu of a case statement. I've also corrected the expression as you've identified my assignment `=` instead of evaluation `==` error ;)